# Different results measuring nanoseconds between GNU date and Python time module

Tags: python, gnu-coreutils

I want to generate a hex of the current number of nanoseconds since unix epoch.  (Doesn't need to be right, just precise)

Here's how you get the current nanoseconds in bash:

```
ksoviero@ksoviero-Latitude-E7440:~$ date +%s%N
1401993044859711108
```

Now, to turn it into a hex, we use `printf`:

```
ksoviero@ksoviero-Latitude-E7440:~$ printf '%x\n' $(date +%s%N)
1374e157ee379028
```

See how easy that was?

Now, let's try to do the same thing with Python.  First, we get the current nanoseconds:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> print int(time() * 10**9)
1401993206893091840
```

Now, we convert it to hex:

```
>>> print format(int(time() * 10**9), 'x')
1374e172f90a6400
```

**I...  What!?  Where did those two zeros at the end come from?**  They're always there, and they're not supposed to be...

Ok, hold on, maybe Python's hex functions can't handle numbers that big.  What happens if we just copy and paste the nanoseconds?

```
>>> print format(1401993044859711108, 'x')
1374e13f086e6e84
```

**Wait, that worked!?**

***Anyone care to guess at what's going on?***  Why does it hex the nanoseconds correctly when given directly, but not when it's the result of a function?

Comment: Kudos on asking a properly formatted (and fun to read) question.

Comment: Wait, aren't there other numbers that varied in that hex?

Comment: Have you tried using `float.hex()` instead? EDIT: nvm, that output is ugly.

Comment: What leads you to believe the two trailing zeros are wrong?

Comment: @chepner, perhaps he expects to only get two trailing zeroes 1/256th of the time. To get it _every_ time is unusual.

Comment: @chepner Yes, Kevin is right.

Comment: It's a lack of precision. Why can't you understand that?

Comment: This isn't a `bash` question in any way whatsoever: The `date` command isn't part of bash, but a standalone tool from GNU coreutils which can be called from any shell or no shell at all.

Comment: ...also, instead of conflating hex conversion and timestamp measurement into one question, it would be better to check which part is inaccurate before asking the question (whether the hex conversion is wrong or the time measurement is lower-accuracy than expected) -- which would let you ask why timestamps measured with Python's `time.time()` always have their low 8 bits as 0s, a better / more focused question.

Answer (score 4):

Because `time.time()` returned a float and the math is leading to precision errors.

Comment: Is there any way to get nanosecond precision in Python?  If you can do it in Bash, then why not?

Comment: Typing that exact question into Google yields several SO questions going back at least 3 years. Read through them to understand the issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want greater precision, let me recommend `time.clock`:

after `import time`

```
>>> format(int(time.clock()* 10**9), 'x')
'baaa3a9e9e9'
>>> format(int(time.clock()* 10**9), 'x')
'baba3cb2a5e'
>>> format(int(time.time()* 10**9), 'x')
'1374e44edaf2e400'
>>> format(int(time.time()* 10**9), 'x')
'1374e4500aeeb700'
```

[The docs on `time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) (the emphasis is mine):

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, **this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.**
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

Regardless, you may be expecting too great of precision for any utility here:

> The precision of the various real-time functions may be less than
>   suggested by the units in which their value or argument is expressed.
>   E.g. on most Unix systems, the clock “ticks” only 50 or 100 times a
>   second.
>
> On the other hand, the precision of time() and sleep() is better than
>   their Unix equivalents: times are expressed as floating point numbers,
>   time() returns the most accurate time available (using Unix
>   gettimeofday() where available), and sleep() will accept a time with a
>   nonzero fraction (Unix select() is used to implement this, where
>   available).

Answer (score 0):

There are no extra zero's at the end. Your mistake is that you're not using the **same time** between the two print statements and you aren't seeing the leading `0x`. If you align your two outputs:

```
0x1374e17396ef0800
  1374e172f90a6400
```

You see there are no extra zeros.

Try the following with a saved time value:

```
>>> now = time()
>>> print format(int(now * 10**9), 'x')
1374e1ffdd1a5300
>>> print hex(int(now * 10**9))
0x1374e1ffdd1a5300
```

You see the outputs are the same. You need to save the output of `time` between these two print statements because otherwise when you call it twice, it will return two different values.

Comment: That's not what I meant, but I can see the confusion.  I literally meant the zeros at the end of both those results, I'm not comparing the two.

Comment: Updated my answer to give an example. It matters that you save the value of `time()` before hand.